# Resize Image on drag maintaining aspect ratio not beyond certain width and height by draggging anchors or lines too

Tags: javascript, html, resize, kineticjs, aspect-ratio

I am using kineticjs I am trying to resize my overlayed picture by dragging anchors or lines.I am able to resize it with anchors but users should also be able to resize it by dragging the blue line. Code is [here](http://jsbin.com/iyimuy/188/) on the JSBin.Also aspect ratio should also be maintained.
ThankYou.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a method to let the user drag the side of an image to resize it**

A demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/8VkLb/

**Left:** original size,  **Right:** being resized by dragging the right side of the image.

[image][image]

This example is for resizing by dragging the right side of an image.

You can modify this technique to let you drag any image side to resize.

**Listen for stage's mousedown events:**

- get the current mouse position
- did the user mousedown near the right side of the image?
- if yes, save the current mouseX position (this is the starting position of the drag)
- Also, save the images starting width and height (needed for proportional scaling)

Mousedown code:

```
$(stage.getContent()).on('mousedown', function (event) {
    var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
    var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
    var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
    var ipos=kImage.position();
    var isize=kImage.getSize();
    var right=ipos.x+isize.width;
    if(mouseX>right-10 && mouseX<right+10){
        startRight=mouseX;
        startWidth=isize.width;
        startHeight=isize.height;
    }
});
```

**Listen for stage's mousemove events:**

- get the current mouse position
- calculate the scaling factor based on how far the user has dragged the mouse from the staring point.
- resize the image using the scaling factor.

Mousemove code:

```
$(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function (event) {
    if(startRight>=0){
        var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
        var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
        var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
        var dx=mouseX-startRight;
        var scaleFactor=(mouseX-(startRight-startWidth))/startWidth;
        kImage.width(startWidth*scaleFactor);
        kImage.height(startHeight*scaleFactor);
        layer.draw();
    }
});
```

**Listen for stage's mouseup events:**

- clear the saved starting drag position (the drag is over)

Mouseup code:

```
$(stage.getContent()).on('mouseup', function (event) {
    startRight=-1;
});
```

Here's full example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
<style>
body{padding:20px;}
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:350px;
  height:350px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: 350,
        height: 350
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    var kImage;
    var startRight=-1;
    var startWidth=0;
    var startHeight=0;

    var img=new Image();
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.onload=start;
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/facesSmall.png";
    function start(){
        kImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            image:img,
            x:10,
            y:10,
            width:img.width,
            height:img.height,
        });
        layer.add(kImage);
        layer.draw();
    }


    $(stage.getContent()).on('mousedown', function (event) {
        var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
        var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
        var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
        var ipos=kImage.position();
        var isize=kImage.getSize();
        var right=ipos.x+isize.width;
        if(mouseX>right-10 && mouseX<right+10){
            startRight=mouseX;
            startWidth=isize.width;
            startHeight=isize.height;
        }
    });


    $(stage.getContent()).on('mouseup', function (event) {
        startRight=-1;
    });


    $(stage.getContent()).on('mousemove', function (event) {
        if(startRight>=0){
            var pos=stage.getPointerPosition();
            var mouseX=parseInt(pos.x);
            var mouseY=parseInt(pos.y);
            var dx=mouseX-startRight;
            var scaleFactor=(mouseX-(startRight-startWidth))/startWidth;
            kImage.width(startWidth*scaleFactor);
            kImage.height(startHeight*scaleFactor);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Drag the right border of the image to resize<br>it while maintaining aspect ratio.</h4>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you be kind enough to edit the fiddle file and add code for the other ends.Moreover we can't drag the image in the fiddle you shared but in my case we can so that's why I was trying to resize the image when we drag the blue line.Thanks for your time

Comment: If you want to drag the image and still allow the bordering 10 pixels of the image to allow resizing, you can specify the hitFunc for the image and exclude the 10 pixels on the outside border of the image.  That way you can drag the image with mousedown on the inside pixels of the image and also resize the image with mousedown on the outside 10 pixels of the image.  (continued on next comment)

Comment: (continued) Using the blue sizing lines is problematical because (1) Any line has a very small grab area which will be irritating for your user to find, (2) When the user drags a blue line, you must reposition that line to align with the newly sized image,  (3) When the user drags 1 blue line you must resize that line and also the 2 lines it's connected to.  Also, if you ever wanted to rotate the image the offset and rotation calculations for the blue lines is quite complex.

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable called "blueline" in your code, you need to modify your code heavily from here on.

When you add the anchors, you need to add 4 separate blue lines which act as anchors as well. Then listen to each line for proper behavior.

```
// blueline1.on('dragstart', function(){ resize('horizontal');}); // for each line
```